# Ошибки в профлите

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, учебные-материалы

Почти каждый из нас читает профлит по разным тематикам и в данных книгах (статьях и т.п) порой встречаются весьма существенные ошибки разного рода: логические, ошибки перевода, либо банальные опечатки.

Все они могут смутить читателя: например ситуация, когда попутали пару символов, скажем икс с игреком, в формуле. Думаю, вы можете представить удивление читателя, особенно когда формула состоит более чем из трёх символов.

Ввиду вышесказаного есть предложение создавать описания по книгам, преимущественно именно по ним, так статью в интернете исправить проще, где бы описывались грубые ошибки, которые бы могли препятствовать обучению.

Например, такой вопрос (здесь на мета или на ruSO) вида "Косяки в книге «Пишем квантовый компьютер на Си»", где было бы сказано примерно следующее:

В главе 3 в формуле 193 спутали два символа + и -, поэтому не ломайте голову и не перепроверяйте.

#### Обновлено

В ответах выразили опасение по поводу проблем с законом при цитировании книг, на основании того, что мол в них добавляют явный запрет на это:

> Никакая часть настоящего издания ни в каких целях не может быть
>   воспроизведена в какой-либо форме и какими бы то ни было средствами,
>   будь то электронные или механические, включая фотокопирование и запись
>   на магнитный носитель, без письменного разрешения издательства ...

И если исходить из этого требования, то и буквами (словами), которые используется в книге пользоваться тоже нельзя?!

Ну а если серьёзно, то, думаю, каждый из вас видел книги где есть цитаты из других книг, статей со ссылками на источник. А это ведь получается нарушение вышеупомянутого требования? Никак нет, так как закон (в РФ это ГК ст. 1274) позволяет цитировать произведения "...без согласия автора или иного правообладателя и без выплаты вознаграждения, но с обязательным указанием имени автора, произведение которого используется, и источника заимствования..." Источник: http://stgkrf.ru/1274

P.S. В других странах есть свои аналогичные законы статье 1274 (иначе бы в зарубежной литературе вы бы не встречали сноски к цитатам).

Comment: После прочтения любой книги я пишу авторам обыкновенно длинные письма об ошибках/неточностях/опечатках, которые, по по поему мнению, имели место быть в ней, — дабы новая редакция издания вышла без них. 8 раз (1 — по книге, [**связанной с тематикой данного сайта**](http://kristinita.ru/Life-hacks/Sublime-Text-Power-User-notes)) мне заплатили даже за это. Такой подход представляется мне лучшим прежде всего для читателей. Спасибо.

Comment: Вообще, с этим предложением можно на area51 зайти, может и взлетит. Расширять on-topic ru.SO такого рода экспериментами я бы воздержался.

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен, что подобные ошибки/опечатки стоит ***специально*** собирать на ruSO, создавая отдельный вопрос по каждой книге. Если кто-то заметил ошибку, то в первую очередь следует уведомить о ней издательство (обычно эта просьба явно присутствует в книге), чтобы в новых изданиях ошибка могла быть исправлена. 
Список найденных ошибок часто публикуется на странице автора книги или издательства. Например, для [The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference, 2nd Edition](http://www.cppstdlib.com/errata.html). Переносить уже найденные ошибки в вопрос на ruSO не считаю целесообразным. Равно как и размещать их первично на ruSO, более того, это может войти в конфликт с некоторыми юридическими аспектами, например из-за явного упоминания об этом в первых страницах книги, вида:

> Никакая часть настоящего издания ни в каких целях не может быть воспроизведена в какой-либо форме и какими бы то ни было средствами, будь то электронные или механические, включая фотокопирование и запись на магнитный носитель, без письменного разрешения издательства ...

Если же кто-то в процессе обучения по какой-то литературе встретит непонятный момент, он может задать ***частный вопрос*** на ruSO (или любом другом сайте) самостоятельно (если не побоится возможных юридических последствий из-за наличия упомянутого выше ограничения). Вполне может быть, что проблема действительно будет крыться в опечатке. Но есть вероятность, что ТС просто чего-то не понял, и ответ будет предполагать более подробное объяснение, нежели просто уведомление об опечатке. Это ещё одна причина того, что не нужно собирать все ошибки по книге в одном вопросе, т.к. помимо простого перечисления хорошо бы иметь и объяснение правильной ситуации. Ведь если вопрос возник, значит не всё так тривиально. В таком случае тело ответа может оказаться слишком раздутым.

Comment: "...чтобы в новых изданиях ошибка могла быть исправлена." - новых изданий может и не быть, а вот вводить в заблуждение текущее издание может.

Comment: "Никакая часть настоящего издания ни в каких целях не может быть воспроизведена в какой-либо форме..." - буквы, используемые в книги, значит тоже под запретом? А если серьёзно, Вы никогда не видели цитат в книгах, где в сносках указаны источники? Думаю, всё таки видели, так как закон это позволяет ГК ст 1274 "Свободное использование произведения в информационных, научных, учебных или культурных целях" http://stgkrf.ru/1274

Comment: @edem если книга востребована и технологии развиваются, то новые издания появляются с большой вероятностью. Но если их всё же действительно нет (пока), то, как я отметил, ничто не мешает задать частный вопрос для прояснения ситуации.

Comment: А что касается графоманства в ответах, то это бывает в любых ответах на ruSO, где авторы склонны к этому.

Comment: В общем, будьте добры дополните свой ответ ссылкой на ст 1274 ГК РФ (для других стран есть аналогичные статьи, так как сноски к цитатам используют не только в России), а так, вместо просвещения людей, своим ответом Вы их просто запугиваете.

Comment: @edem я не юрист, поэтому не могу утверждать точно, где та тонкая грань между цитированием и незаконным распространением. Сослался на вполне конкретный текст предупреждения из книги. Надеюсь, что этим я не нарушил этот же самый запрет :)

Answer (score 2):

> "Косяки в книге «Пишем квантовый компьютер на Си»"
>
> В главе 3 в формуле 193 спутали два символа + и -, поэтому не ломайте голову и не перепроверяйте.

Так не годится. Надо

1. Подогнать как-то под формат, в котором это поисковики хотя бы находить будут
2. Подогнать под разделение на вопрос и ответ, чтобы неотвеченные вопросы не висели

Comment: 1. Обсуждаемый момент. 2. Вопрос - название книги. Ответы - описание косяков в них.